# SQL запрос в базу данных книжного магазина

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть база данных с двумя таблицами. В первой таблице представлена информация о книгах. Во второй таблице находится список издательств книг.

Поля первой таблицы: `id, Название_книги, Количество_страниц, id_издательства`.
(*id_издательства* - внешний ключ).

Поля второй таблицы: `id, Название_издательства`.

Как будет выглядеть sql запрос, который выдаст список всех издательств и для каждого издательства выдаст название книги этого издательства с наибольшим количеством страниц.

Comment: Укажите используемый SQL сервер, и его версию, запросы будут кардинально отличатся для MSSQL\MySQL\PGSQL

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1):

Согласно вашим названиям:

```
Select name_izd, 
(Select Top(1) name_book from First_table f_t 
Where f_t.id_izd=s_t.id 
Order by id_izd, count_pages desc) As [count_pages] 
from Second_table s_t
```

- Поле name_izd - Название_издательства
- Поле name_book - Название_книги
- Поле id_izd - id_издательства
- Поле count_pages - Количество_страниц